# Play2 template cannot find model class

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm going through the play2 tutorial (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaTodoList) but my template cannot find my model class (which I'm calling Check, as opposed to 'Task' in the tutorial.  Here's what I get:

```
Compilation error

not found: type Check
```

I tried adding an import for my class too (@import model.Check) but I got this:

```
Compilation error

not found: value model
```

Any ideas?  I'm got over and over the steps but I must still be missing something.

Comment: So you can just delete the question as it's de facto just mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my Check class in 'model', not 'models'.

Comment: It's always plural - `models`, `views`, `controllers`, `services`.